# Create Data in Laravel-8 Project not working, how to solve it?

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-7, laravel-8

I have a problem to add data or create data in my project laravel, how to solve it? i really confused for this

this is the controller

```
     namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use App\Models\DaftarPelanggan;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use \Illuminate\Http\Response;
    use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    use Alert;
    
    class DaftarPelangganController extends Controller
    {
    public function validator(Request $request)
        {
            return Validator::make($data, [
                'nama_pelanggan' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
                'alamat' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
                'no_telp' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            ]);
        }
    
        public function create(Request $request)
        {
            return DaftarPelanggan::create([
                'nama_pelanggan' => $data['addNamaPelanggan'],
                'alamat' => $data['addAlamat'],
                'no_telp' => $data['addNoTelp'],
                'email' => $data['addEmail'],
                'poin' => $data['addPOin'],
                'status_member' => $data['addKategori'],
            ]);
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
```

this is the Routing

```
Route::get('daftar_pelanggan/create','\App\Http\Controllers\DaftarPelangganController@create')->name('daftar_pelanggan.create');
```

this is the button blade

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">
    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
```

and this is the modal form

```
    <!-- Modal  Add -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="addModal" tabindex="-2" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title mb-0" id="addModalLabel">Tambah Data Pelanggan</h5>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- Card body -->
                    <form role="form" action="{{ route('daftar_pelanggan.create') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                 <!-- Input groups with icon -->
                     <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="addNamaPelanggan" class="col-md-2 col-form-label form-control-label">Nama</label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                          <input class="form-control" type="nama" placeholder="Nama Lengkap" id="addNamaPelanggan" name="addNamaPelanggan">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="addAlamat" class="col-md-2 col-form-label form-control-label">Alamat</label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                          <input class="form-control" type="alamat" placeholder="Jatibarang" id="addAlamat" name="addAlamat">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="addNoTelp" class="col-md-2 col-form-label form-control-label">No.Telp</label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                          <input class="form-control" type="notelp" placeholder="083XXXXXXXXX" id="addNoTelp" name="addNoTelp">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="addEmail" class="col-md-2 col-form-label form-control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="addEmail" placeholder="name@example.com" name="addEmail">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-control-label" for="addPoin">POIN</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addPoin" placeholder="0" name="addPoin">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-control-label" for="addKategori">Kategori</label>
                              <select class="form-control" id="addKategori" name="addKategori">
                                <option value="silver">Silver</option>
                                <option value="gold">Gold</option>
                                <option value="diamond">Diamond</option>
                              </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Tambah Data</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

and this is the model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DaftarPelanggan extends Model
{
    //use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $table = "daftar_pelanggans";
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [
       'nama_pelanggan',
       'alamat',
       'no_telp',
       'email',
       'poin',
       'status_member',
   ];
}
```

Please help me thank you
[modals form my project][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnSyI.png

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what error your gettig ?

Comment: the button tambah data not working and the controller create data not work, what's wrong with my code?

Comment: have you try debug?

Comment: yes i have, i think the query insert it's not execute

Comment: "I think" is pretty broad - what have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The button is outside the form tag you should try it inside the form tag

Comment: thank you its working, but i change your controller code

Comment: What was the problem and how does your code help solve it?

Comment: @showdev the button is not inside the form you can see the pervious discussion where i am exactly see the problem and this answer actually work for him

Comment: @showdev read discussion carefully before any comment

Comment: Which discussion? In my view, the most useful answers include a self-contained explanation, not just "try this".

Answer (score 2):

In addition to your inputs, your `submit` button must be inside your form tags.

Comment: I have answered him in my way @RushikeshGanesh ,and it seems that you have edited your own answer... so basically it's not ME who copied YOUR answer. have a nice day (ps : yes i'm the 1 who have upvoted your answer).

Answer (score 1):

You are using route with method 'get' to access the controller

Route::get('daftar_pelanggan/create','\App\Http\Controllers\DaftarPelangganController@create')->name('daftar_pelanggan.create');

change to 'post' like this

Route::post('daftar_pelanggan/create','\App\Http\Controllers\DaftarPelangganController@create')->name('daftar_pelanggan.create');

Comment: yes it's a good practice to submit a form using POST method instead of GET, but this is not the exact problem. But still a good answer.